# Allow S3 bucket top-level listing to specific users only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Scenario:

I have an S3 bucket which contains "directories" inside it.

```
my-bucket/xxx
my-bucket/yyy
my-bucket/zzz
etc
```

I have 2 groups of users: admin and user.

Admin should be able to list/view everying inside the bucket, that is, at the top level, for e.g. `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket`.

User cannot view the top-level, but can list/view inside every directory in the bucket.

I am not sure how to define such a policy and where to attach it - on the S3 bucket or IAM user side. I have tried both options. Doesn't work.

User side:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

S3 bucket side:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/User"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **do not use a Bucket Policy**. A bucket policy is typically used when granting access to "everyone".

If you wish to grant access to a specific user, put the policy on the **IAM User**.

If you wish to grant access to a group of users, put them in an IAM Group and put the policy on the **IAM Group**.

Here is a policy that allows listing of a particular bucket, **except for the top-level (root) directory:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "*/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It's basically giving them permission to list the bucket, as long as the `Prefix` (path) contains a slash (`/`).

Please note that if you are listing a bucket, you *must* include the slash after the directory name:

```
aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET-NAME/folder/
```

This will *not* work because it does not contain a slash:

```
aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET-NAME/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict access to "folders" in S3 by applying conditions on the IAM policies.

[How can I grant a user access to a specific folder in my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-folder-user-access/)

Comment: this solution does not restrict top level listing by user.